# Why Is the Canny Edge Detection Used Instead of Sobel / Prewitt Edge Detection Before Hough Transformation?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform, canny-edge-detector, image-analysis

I know that for the Hough Transform to work on an image, it needs to be a binary image. To convert from a grayscale image, an edge detection algorithm should be employed. I notice that people always use Canny edge detection instead of others (e.g., Sobel). Why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Canny Edge Detection is considered to be a better (In False Alarm sense) edge detection than those you mentioned.
This is, mainly, due to 2 steps:

1. Non Maximum Suppression - Edges candidates which are not dominant in their neighborhood aren't considered to be edges.
2. Hysteresis Process - While moving along the candidates, given a candidate which is in the neighborhood of an edge the threshold is lower.

Those 2 steps reduce the number of "False" edges and hence create a better starting point for farther process like Hough Transformation.

Answer (score 6):

Your statement that the Hough transform (HT) needs to be applied on a binary image is not true. The original HT indeed was formulated that way, though in the meanwhile different authors extended the HT in numerous ways -- for example, to consider the gray scale values of each image pixel. As a consequence, the step of edge detection can be omitted.

Citations concerning grey scale values taken from [Extraction of Spatial Ultrasonic Wave Packet Features by Exploiting a Modified Hough Transform](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/JSEN.2014.2311160):

> [23] F. O’Gorman and M. B. Clowes, “Finding picture edges through
> collinearity of feature points,” IEEE Trans. Comput., vol. 25, no. 4,
> pp. 449–456, Apr. 1976.
>
> [24] J. Skingley and A. J. Rye, “The Hough transform applied to SAR
> images for thin line detection,” Pattern Recognit. Lett., vol. 6, no.
> 1, pp. 61–67,
> 1987.
>
> [25] C. Trayner, N. J. Bailey, and B. R. Haynes, “Time-gradient Hough
> transforms–constraining object identification by speed of motion,”
> Real-Time Imag., vol. 6, no. 2, pp. 143–153, 2000.

Comment: Agreed, after posting this question, I have also read that the HT does not require a binary input image. Thanks!